# Why does an input of char in place of int always display value zero?

Tags: c++, architecture, cin

The following is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
  int num;
  cout<<"Enter a number: ";
  cin>>num;
  cout<<"The number is: "<<num;

  return 0;
}
```

If I enter a character or a string instead of an integer on the prompt for `cin>>num`, the value of `num` is returned as `0` everytime. Is it because it has been implemented that way in C++ or am I missing some trivial concept? Any answer would be of great help.

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings Really?

Comment: @AsteroidsWithWings haha I mean what does  he awaits to see after. my bet is char scan code

Comment: so it were double entendre thing. did you catch it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a feature introduced in C++11. From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt);

before:

> If extraction fails (e.g. if a letter was entered where a digit is expected), value is left unmodified and failbit is set.
> (until C++11)

now:

> If extraction fails, zero is written to value and failbit is set. If extraction results in the value too large or too small to fit in value, std::numeric_limits::max() or std::numeric_limits::min() is written and failbit flag is set. (since c++11)

Note that before C++11 your code potentially invokes undefined behavior. If input fails you are using `num` uninitialized. In that case, `0` as output was just as valid as any other output (because undefined behavior is undefined).

Comment: Thank you! I do need to learn my way around cppreference :)

Comment: @Anjishnu some areas of the standard library are notorisouly difficicult for beginners (at least it was for me). When you read `std::basic_istream<CharT,Traits>::somehting` then for now you can read that as `std::istream::something`, it looks a bit more complicated than it actually is

Answer (score 0):

Istreams objects have flags to detect bad input: whenever bad input is passed to cin there'll be a bad input flag set. By calling `cin.fail()` and checking if it evaluates to true you can actively monitor if input wasn't correct. In that case, cin will assign value 0 to the variable you passed.